# MySql OR and AND Operation

Tags: mysql

my table schema as follows:

```
                      +------+-------+-------+                                                                                                                                                         
                      | id   | name1 | name2 |                                                                                          
                      +------+-------+-------+                                                                                        
                      |    1 | A     | B     |
                      |    2 | A     | C     |
                      |    3 | B     | A     |
                      |    4 | C     | D     |
                      +------+-------+-------+
```

and i am using the query as follows:

```
          select * from t where name1='A' or name1='B' and name2='C';
```

and the result as follows

```
                       +------+-------+-------+
                       | id   | name1 | name2 |
                       +------+-------+-------+
                       |    1 | A     | B     |
                       |    2 | A     | C     |
                       +------+-------+-------+
```

How this result came and

I want the query which returns the row that in which the name1 will be **A** or **B** and name2 to be **'B'**

the query result should be like this

```
                       +------+-------+-------+
                       | id   | name1 | name2 |
                       +------+-------+-------+
                       |    1 | A     | B     |
                       +------+-------+-------+
```

I want the result from the query using only "AND" and "OR" operation...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL logical operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690763/mysql-logical-operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read up about [boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_Logic). This is a very simple operation, so if you were familiar with B.L.,  you'd have been able to do this yourself.

That being said, these two states will accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (name1 IN ('A', 'B')) AND (name2 = 'B')
SELECT ... WHERE ((name1 = 'A') or (name1 = 'B')) AND (name2 = 'B')
```

Comment: Can anyone explain how the  query   select * from t where name1='A' or name1='B' and name2='C'; executes and gives two rows as result

Comment: because it's seen as name1=A OR (name1=b and name2=c). note the brackets. `or` binds tighter than `and`. boolean algebra has order-of-operations, just like regular algebra (e.g. the old BEDMAS mnenomic: brackets, exponents, division, multiplication, addition, subtraction).

Answer (score 0):

group your condition by adding parenthesis

```
select * from t where (name1='A' or name1='B') and name2='B';
```

OR use `IN`

```
select * from t where name1 IN ('A','B') and name2='B';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use parentheses

```
select * from t where name1='A' or name1='B' and name2='C';
```

should be

```
select * from t where (name1='A' or name1='B') and name2='B';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select * from t where (name1='A' or name1='B') and name2='B';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a precedence issue. The B and C clauses are binding together meaning you're getting:

```
select * from t where name1='A' or (name1='B' and name2='B');
```

So what you need to do is explicitly bind the clauses yourself:

```
select * from t where (name1='A' or name1='B') and name2='B';
```

(assuming your use of C in your stated query was a typo, since it didn't match the rest of your question).